# How to do a Http POST of a string with rxSendStream of io.vertx.reactivex.ext.web.client.WebClient

Tags: rx-java2, vert.x, vertx-httpclient

I am new to Vertx and Rx Java. I want to do a Http POST , but my content is a string. Here is my code :

```java
Single<HttpResponse<Buffer>> single = webClient
  .post(apiUrl)          
  .rxSendStream(body);
```

and body can be any of the following:

- `Flowable<Buffer>` body or
- `Observable<Buffer>` body or
- `Buffer` body

My question is how do i convert body to any of the above types

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is this:

```java
WebClient webClient = WebClient.create(vertx);
String body  = "";
webClient.post(apiUrl)
   .rxSendBuffer(Buffer.buffer(body))
   .subscribe(resp -> {
     System.out.println(resp.body().toString());
   });
```